# mailx execute successfully but not sending mail out

Tags: solaris, mailx

I'm using mailx and sendmail functions to send mail from set of **solaris** machine with different versions. And the script send mail for most of the machine. Still issue is there on sending out mail for few servers. But there is no error shown while execute this script.

**Script 1:**

```
uuencode report.html report.html | mailx -s "mail subject" testaddress@domain.com
```

Script 2:

```
SELFDIR=`pwd`
DOCROOT=$SELFDIR"/"
MAIL_FROM="donotreply@mydom.com"
MAIL_TO="myname@mydom.com"

echo "From: "$MAIL_FROM > $DOCROOT"header.txt"
echo "To: "$MAIL_TO >> $DOCROOT"header.txt"
echo "Subject:  The mail subject  " >> $DOCROOT"header.txt"
echo "Content-Type: text/html" >> $DOCROOT"header.txt"

cat $DOCROOT"header.txt" $DOCROOT"report.html" | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

Simply is there any way to find the error or logs of the mail delivery failed to recognize the reason of failture?

Comment: I don't think Solaris' sendmail creates a log by default, but it may be bouncing mails back to root or some other user with delivery failures, or the mail could be stuck in the queue (check `mailq` as root).

Comment: Does your `report.html` file start with a blank line?  you need to have at least one blank line between the message headers and the message body.  If it's your `report.html` doesn't start with a blank line, just add `echo >> "${DOCROOT}header.txt"`immediately before the `cat` (it doesn't hurt to do that anyway because an extra blank line is harmless).   BTW `sendmail` should be logging to wherever facility `mail` is being sent on your system - probably /var/log/mail.log or similar, try `grep mail /etc/syslog.conf` to verify that.

Comment: btw, you really should put the double-quotes around the variable as i did above (i.e. `"${DOCROOT}header.txt"`).  If the current dir contains a space or other annoying character somewhere in the path, your script will fail.

Comment: After running `sendmail`  run `mail` and check mails from your mai server. If there is a problem with your mail it might send you a mail with a error description.

Comment: @ EightBitTony mailq is return empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I last used `sendmail` on Solaris but I'm sure its `-v` flag will show what's going on:

```
(
    echo 'From: me@example.net'
    echo 'To: you@contoso.com'
    echo 'Subject: from me to you'
    echo
    finger
) | sendmail -t -v
```

I'm also pretty sure that `mailx` passes this flag onwards:

```
echo hello, world | mailx -v -s "mail subject" bill@contoso.com
```

Check `/var/log/syslog` for `sendmail` messages. Also take a read of [The ultimate Solaris sendmail troubleshooting guide](http://thegeekdiary.com/the-ultimate-solaris-sendmail-troubleshooting-guide/) which helps with differences between Solaris versions 8, 9, 10.

Comment: I try the verbos mode it return following path: /export/home/sugu/dead.letter. Is this giving a clue?

Comment: @sugunan I would have expected it to have given you somewhere between 5 and 35 lines of output. Are you sure it didn't? (If it did, please add those lines to your question, explaining where it came from.)

Comment: No it didn't gave. Only this line came up.

Comment: `mailx: unrecognized option '-v'`

Comment: @alper using Solaris or a Linux variant?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly improved version of your script.  It uses `$(pwd)` rather than back-ticks, single-quotes around literal strings (the From and To addresses, and the subject string), double-quotes where variable interpolation is needed, and uses a heredoc for the headers rather than multiple `echo` lines.  I like to use the string `__EOF__` to delimit heredocs because it's unlikely to occur in the body of the heredoc...any arbitrary string would work as well.

Note the final blank line before the end of the heredoc - a blank line is **required** to separate message headers and body.

BTW, variables are interpolated inside heredocs in the same way as for double-quoted strings.  You can even use command substitution `$(...)` in them.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

DOCROOT=$(pwd)
$header="$DOCROOT/header.txt"
$body="$DOCROOT/report.html"

MAIL_FROM='donotreply@mydom.com'
MAIL_TO='myname@mydom.com'
$subject='The mail subject'

cat <<__EOF__ > "$header"
From: $MAIL_FROM
To: $MAIL_TO
Subject: $subject
Content-Type: text/html

__EOF__

cat "$header" "$body" | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

Let me know if that fixes your problem.

BTW to answer your actual question, `sendmail` should be logging to wherever facility mail is being sent on your system - possibly `/var/log/mail.log` or similar, try `grep mail /etc/syslog.conf` to verify that.